# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в Windows Form, начиналось выполнение .cpp кода?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки в Windows Form, начиналось выполнение .cpp файла из проекта?

Comment: Абсолютно не понимаю.  Есть готовый код в проекте. Нужно его запустить после того как нажмётся кнопка в Windows Form.

Comment: А что Вы понимаете под "выполнением .cpp файла"? Он как бы может компилироваться, но как он может выполняться, я не понимаю.

Comment: @qwertygod: А вы умеете по нажатию кнопки запустить _хоть какой-то_ код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код C++ (находящийся в файле с расширением .cpp) необходимо откомпилировать.

Обычно для компиляции кода используется наследник CodeDomProvider'а. Хотя существует Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeProvider, но использовать его невозможно, так как вызов метода CreateCompiler приводит к исключению System.NotImplementedException.

Для компиляции C++ кода из WinForms приложения можно вызвать MSBuild. 
Посмотрите MSDN: [Пошаговое руководство. Использование MSBuild для создания проекта Visual C++.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd293607.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
private:
    void Button_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        //...
    }
```